# Having trouble getting the selenium command line to run HTML tests and record output, then exit w/ status that reflects test result

Tags: selenium

I am having trouble running selenium on my Mac so that it runs a simple suite with one simple test (see sections 'TEST CASE' and 'TEST SUITE', below) using the following command line:

java -jar lib/selenium-server.jar  -timeout 10   -log server.log -browserSideLog browser.log  -debug -htmlSuite '*firefox' http://google.com `pwd`/suite3 `pwd`/selenium.html

My problem is that i don't get a non-zero return code as expected when tests fail, and also, i don't see any reports.

I have tried the following variants:

Using the given suite and testcase files   either:

- specify  -timeout option (ends drastically with no reports being written), or
- do not specify the -timeout option. 
  without the time out option the selenium server never shuts down... even though the help documentation says:

  ```
  Run a single HTML Selenese (Selenium Core) suite and then exit
  immediately, using the specified browser (e.g. "*firefox") on the
  specified URL (e.g. "http://www.google.com").
  ```

To get around the hang i added an extra selenium command to the test case to force shut down of the server, as follows:

```
....  previous commands ...
          <tr>
            <td>open</td>
            <td>http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

This did eliminate the hang.  The browser shut down and the process terminated.. but i got no test results, and my exit code was (incorrectly) zero... not
non-zero as i would have expected.

TEST SUITE   (this needs to be saved with the name 'suite3' )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="selenium.base" href="http://google.com" />
    <title>testcase3</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">testcase3</td></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>open</td>
          <td>/</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
          <td>xbout Google</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

TEST CASE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="selenium.base" href="http://google.com" />
    <title>testcase3</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">testcase3</td></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>open</td>
          <td>/</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>verifyTextPresent</td>
          <td>xbout Google</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance to whoever can give me a clue to solve this !
  - chris

Answer (score 6):

Our colleague in Beijing, Chenyun Xiao, figured out the trick here. If you rename both the suite and testcase file so they have .html extensions (and u make sure that the ref from suite to testcase is updated to reflect the new name for the test case file) then everything will work as expected.. Thanks, Chenyun – Chris Bedford 1 min ago

Comment: Despite the lack of a best answer checkbox, and the ludicrousness that a missing file extension could cause this hanging error — this answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use java for your testsuite and testcase.

I encountered coded vanishes when dealing with the html selenium code.

Comment: Our colleague in Beijing, Chenyun Xiao, figured out the trick here. If you rename both the suite and testcase file so they have .html extensions  (and u make sure that the ref from suite to testcase is updated to reflect the new name for the test case file) then everything will work as expected..   Thanks, Chenyun

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a solution using Selenium Server (formerly RC) but I don't know it off-hand. And I'm on a project that keeps me from researching it.

PushToTest TestMaker has a great command-line interface to run Selenese Table Format scripts in a desktop, grid, or cloud environment. Check out the tutorial at http://www.pushtotest.com/web-testing-with-selenium-pushtotest to see how it all fits together.

-Frank